# Trouble with Java Script applying hover state to div

Tags: javascript, html, hover, children, nav

My coworker helped me with this script today, and it works fine in my test sample, but when I try to incorporate it into my site design it doesn't work. The object is to use a div(boxEnd) to skew and round the corners at the end of the menu bar and apply the hover state of the last menu item(menlast). In my sample I only had one 'a' element, but when I added a second, the hover state was applied to the div by both 'a' elements. So I need to fix the current code to utilize the script, and figure out how to only call the script when the last menu item is in hover.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('a').children('#boxEnd').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('a').children('#boxEnd').css('background-color','#ff2d0a');
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- TOP NAV -->

<div id="NAVcontainer">
<div align="center" id="topnav">
  <div align="left" id="logo"><img src="images/mml-3-24-264x102.png"/></div>
  <div align="left" id="menu">
    <nav> 
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a id="menlast" href="#contact">Contact
    <div id="boxEnd">&emsp;</div></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here was my final solution: http://jsfiddle.net/shockabout/b7j39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you daisy chain $().children it doesn't grab all the children of all the children.  It's only going to get the children of the first child.  If this is your actual HTML then you want

```
$('nav').hover(function() { $('#boxEnd').css(...); });
```

There's no need to consider the relationship between nav and #boxEnd.  $('#boxEnd') is always going to find the right div.

This assumes that the code you posted is your attempt to fix your problem, not what you had originally after you added the second 'a'.  If that's wrong I'll edit this with more details.

Comment: This didn't limit the css being applied on just one 'a' element, but I'll have to double check my id's to see if I can isolate the div further.

Comment: Here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/shockabout/gLSwS/4/  I need to find a way to isolate the script to function only on the last 'a' element.

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of having the DIV inside the A element, I just moved it to the end still inside the NAV element. Then I assigned an ID to the last A element, calling the HOVER function on that last A element and it works perfectly. Thanks for your input, you've both been a great help!

Answer (score 0):

just add .end() after .children('a')
http://api.jquery.com/end/
.end() Description: End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

so essentially 
      $(this).children('a').end().children('#boxEnd').css('background-color','#ffffff');

see the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/v3szF/5/

```
 $('nav').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('a').end().children('#boxEnd').css('background-color','#ffffff');
}, function() {
    $(this).children('a').end().children('#boxEnd').css('background-color','#ff2d0a');
});
```

Comment: This stopped the css being applied to the div all together.

Comment: it does not stop the css from being applied when you hover over the background is white when you hover off the background turns orange or whatever color that is - works perfectly

Comment: I'll break it down and give it another try. Then see if I can built it back up.I'll let you know what happens. Thanks. :)

Comment: Okay this is the code with your script and you'll get an idea of what I want to happen. The div on the end defines the end of the menu bar and it needs to change color with the last "Contact" button.  http://jsfiddle.net/shockabout/gLSwS/

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of having the DIV inside the A element, I just moved it to the end still inside the NAV element. Then I assigned an ID to the last A element, calling the HOVER function on that last A element and it works perfectly. Thanks for your input, you've both been a great help!